# Are the less common forms of the passé simple not widely known?

Tags: usage, temps-grammatical, passé-simple

The third person singular and plural forms, as well as first person singular form, are no doubt very common as the standard voice of the narrator in written works.

But for second person singular/plural and first person plural, I would imagine it's markedly less so. Are those conjugations (and for the imparfait du subjonctif as well) as rare as I'm guessing? And does that mean many people don't even know them? I realize for the regular verbs they just follow a pattern, but for the irregular verbs, surely that must border on uncommon knowledge.

Or are the patterns sufficient to know them all just by knowing a few?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Les conjugaisons des 1er et 2e groupes ne sont pas particulièrement problématiques (à part pour la tendance à écrire -at à la 3e personne du singulier). Beaucoup de personnes hésiteront sur la conjugaison correcte des verbes irréguliers. Même pour quelqu'un qui lit beaucoup, comme cette conjugaison est une connaissance passive, et non active.

Il est si rare pour la vaste majorité des gens d'avoir à écrire un passé simple que je ne vois pas pourquoi on le leur reprocherait. La plupart des anglophones ne sauraient pas utiliser le subjonctif anglais, et j'ai connu plus de francophones que d'anglophones capable de différencier *lie* et *lay*, nous n'avons donc pas le monopole dans le domaine.

Le passé simple n'est pas nécessairement le temps où il y a le plus de variation. J'ai trouvé des variantes au futur pour *asseoir*, *résoudre* et *craindre*, par exemple. Je dois admettre qu'il est dur de battre les ***trois*** différentes formes attestées pour le passé simple des dérivés de *traire* (Ce verbe n'est plus usité, mais beaucoup de gens ont eu besoin d'un passé simple pour *distraire*, *soustraire* ou *extraire*!).

---

The conjugations of the first and second verb groups are hardly problematic (except for the a tendency to write -at at the 3rd person singular). A lot of people will hesitate on the correct conjugation of irregular verb, though, and even for an avid reader like me, that conjugation is passive, not active knowledge.

In general, it's so rare for people to actually need to write down a passé simple that I don't see why you should judge someone over it. Most English-speakers can't use the subjunctive properly, and I know more foreign than native speakers of English that can tell *lie* and *lay* apart (I can barely manage sometimes, myself), so French hardly has a monopoly on this sort of thing.

The passé simple isn't even necessarily the tense where the most variation is seen: I've found alternate future conjugations for *asseoir*, *résoudre* et *craindre*. Still it's hard to beat the ***three*** different forms found in the passé simple for the verbs derived from *traire* (That verb may have fallen out of use, but many people have needed a passé simple form for *distraire*, *soustraire* ou *extraire*!).

Comment: I don't understand this bit about *traire*....I looked and can't find *any* passe simple conjugation for it, let alone three different ones. What's going on here??

Comment: It's easy for grammar writers to pretend that (say) *extraire* has no passé simple. People who actually speak and write French? They can and *will* conjugate it in that tense and a linguist can't afford to dismiss these as mere mistakes. Try a google book search for "il extraya" and see for yourself! This is no different from the American conjugating *dive* as *dove* in the past participle, but the brits conjugate it as *dived*.

Comment: @Circeus Well, defectiveness and insecurity should not be ignored either. If you ask an American speaker about DIVE, his reaction will probably depend upon which form he uses first: preterit *dived* or past participle *dove*. In my experience, producing a first form is easy but the second one makes the speaker insecure. As for French, *closons* is also found in Google Books searches but its frequency compared to *clôturons* (and the opposite distribution of *closent/clôturent*) still leans towards defectiveness.

Comment: @GAMPUB My point is more that the "defectiveness" of many verbs has been somewhat artificially maintained because somehow the idea that a form of the verb might be reconstructed when needed *really* grates on the mind of the French grammarian. The primary reason a verb like *distraire* is held as defective is not that it has no natural passé simple (*nous nous distrayâmes* just rolls off the tongue instinctively), but rather because Bescherelle says it has the conjugation of *traire*, which virtually nobody nowadays puts in the passé simple (apparently, the original form was *traisîmes*, BTW)

Comment: Which is precisely the point of defectiveness. But what do you have to say about clore/cloturer?

Comment: Then I have to say that you have again completely missed my point and I'm not sure any further arguing on my part would be constructive.

Answer (score 3):

Some forms of conjugations are becoming obsolete and are more and more used in books and in elevated languages forms only. The *passé simple de l'indicatif* and the *imparfait du subjonctif* are in this case, as well as their compound forms, i.e. the *passé antérieur de l'indicatif* and the *plus-que-parfait du subjonctif*. The *passé composé* is replacing the *passé simple* at the indicative mode and the *imparfait* at the subjunctive mood. As for anteriority, the *plus-que-parfait de l'indicatif* is replacing the *passé antérieur de l'indicatif*. Conditional past tenses (1st and 2nd forms) are also disappearing. However some expressions containing those deprecated past tenses will remain in the language, as a relic of their bright past.

These things prove that the French idiom is not dead at all. It is still alive.

---

Certaines formes de conjugaisons sont en train de tomber en désuétude et ne sont plus employées que dans la littérature ou bien dans des formes de langages très soutenues. C'est le cas du passé simple de l'indicatif et de l'imparfait du subjonctif, mais aussi de leurs formes composées, c'est-à-dire le passé antérieur de l'indicatif et le plus-que-parfait du subjonctif. Le passé composé remplace progressivement le passé simple à l'indicatif et l'imparfait au subjonctif. Pour ce qui est de l'antériorité le plus-que-parfait de l'indicatif prend progressivement la place du passé antérieur de l'indicatif. Les formes de conditionnel passé disparaissent progressivement elles aussi. De ceci il ne restera bientôt que des tournures de langages toutes faites comme des vestiges d'un temps passé.

Cela prouve que le Français n'est pas une langue morte, bien au contraire.

Comment: Le passé simple que dans la littérature?  Peut-être, mais y compris la littérature enfantine. Il me semble avoir déjà fait mention que lors d'une précédente discussion sur le sujet j'avais échantillonné les livres pour enfants ne sachant pas encore lire que j'avais à la maison et qu'un quart en faisait usage (ce qui faisait la moitié de ceux écrit au passé, et pas uniquement les plus vieux) et que peu après le conteur d'un spectacle (à nouveau destiné à des enfants en age pré-scolaire) l'avait utilisé.  C'est un temps du récit élaboré, oui, mais tombant en désuétude, je ne suis pas aussi sur.

Comment: C'est sûr que c'est un peu moins vrai que pour le passé simple que pour les autres. Mais il n'empêche que de moins en moins de personnes parlent courremment au passé simple de l'indicatif.

Comment: Le conditionnel passé disparait ? Tiens j'aurais pas cru !