# Est-ce que les francophones natifs sont familiers avec toutes les conjugaisons du passé simple?

Tags: verbes, conjugaison, passé-simple

Il me semble que les conjugaisons les plus courantes du passé simple sont la troisième personne du singulier et la troisième personne du pluriel, et peut-être la première personne du singulier.
Mais la première personne du pluriel et la deuxième personne du singulier *et* pluriel sont très rares, n'est-ce pas?

La plupart des gens connaissent-ils ces conjugaisons, soit pour une raison que je ne connais pas, soit parce qu'ils les ont étudiées à l'école, soit parce qu'ils connaissent les terminaisons si bien que connaitre les 1<sup>re</sup> et 3<sup>e</sup> personnes du singulier et la 3<sup>e</sup> du pluriel est suffisant pour les connaitre toutes?

---

It seems to me that the first person plural and both the singular and plural of the second person conjugations are extremely rare in the passe simple, almost unheard of.

Do native French speakers still know the full conjugation, either for some reason I haven't thought of, or because they studied them in school, or because they just know the conjugation patterns so well that knowing the first/third singular and third plural is enough to know all of them?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez I seem to have accidentally asked the same question twice. Drat. http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8115/are-the-less-common-forms-of-the-pass%C3%A9-simple-not-widely-known I was going through my old questions to accept various answers that I hadn't taken care of, and added a bounty to that one, then saw this one.